# Guardians of the Galaxy 2 original ravagers team member

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In a *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol:2* post-credit scene we see original Ravager captains get back together.

There was this woman looking very similar to Hela.

Are they another species?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to the dark haired woman played by Michelle Yeoh shown at the bottom of the image here.

[image]

This is ALETA OGORD (also known as "Starhawk")...I'll let [**Nerdist.com**](http://nerdist.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-who-were-those-new-ravagers-spoilers-sylvester-stallone-michelle-yeoh-ving-rhames-miley-cyrus/) explain

> Ok, this is where things get weird. Aleta Ogord was born with light manipulating powers, but that’s not the weird part. She was raised by an awful father, but she fell for her adopted brother Stakar and eventually married him (creepy). The two encountered a powerful Hawk God, who was able to merge Stakar and Aleta in the super powerful cosmic being with a very silly costume named Starhawk.

**NO**, Aleta is not of Asgardian origin (at least in the comics). We don't know exactly what role she will play in any future MCU movie.

<sup>[**More reading @ ComicVine**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/aleta-ogord/4005-15994/)</sup>